# Magento 2 Free Shipping options showing all the time in cart page

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I have two shipping methods, a flat rate and a free shipping option over $100. Under Stores>Configuration>Sales>Shipping Methods, I have selected 'NO' for show method if not applicable for Flat rate. That would hide it ideally if the order is over $100.

But both methods are showing. How can I hide flat rate if the order amount is over $100?

Comment: Check in particular store view there is set NO

Comment: I did that, but it is still showing !